# Enviar objeto original a un vector en vez de su copia C++

Tags: c++, array, poo, class

Tengo la siguiente clase

```
#pragma once


#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Unit
{
public:

    Unit();
    ~Unit();

    int ID;
    int range;
    std::string name;

    void Init(int,int,std::string);

};
```

Y quiero crear una serie de objetos de esta clase en el vector "activeUnits" los cuales posteriormente tendré que eliminar (primero eliminarlos del vector, y despues destruirlos como tal). El problema es que si muevo los objetos al vector de la siguiente manera:

```
                std::vector<Unit> activeUnits;
                Unit Unit1;
                Unit1.Init(1,1,"test");
                activeUnits.push_back(Unit1);
```

Lo que estoy haciendo es enviar una copia del objeto al vector. De manera que si despues borro el objeto presente en el vector, solo estare borrando una copia y no el objeto original (que es lo que quiero hacer). Habia pensado en hacer un vector de punteros que apunten hacia los objetos originales pero tampoco parece funcionar.

Hay alguna manera de enviar los objetos originales al vector sin copiarlos?

O existe alguna manera de borrar los objetos originales mediante su copia?

Comment: Si guardas punteros en el vector, cuando un objeto deje de existir, habrá punteros que apunten a memoria no válida así que tendrás que actualizar el vector manualmente. Tal vez con punteros inteligentes sea más fácil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construye el objeto directamente dentro del vector, de esta manera no tienes que mover nada:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Unit> activeUnits;

    activeUnits.emplace_back();
    activeUnits.back().Init(1,1,"test");

    return 0;
}
```

Si creas un constructor con parámetros (en lugar de usar la función `Unit::Init`), la operación es más directa:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Unit
{
    Unit(int id, int r, const std::string &n) :
        ID{id},
        range{r},
        name{n}
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor:\t" << this << '\n';
    }

    ~Unit() { std::cout << "Destructor:\t" << this << '\n'; }

private:
    int ID;
    int range;
    std::string name;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Unit> activeUnits;

    activeUnits.emplace_back(1, 1, "test");

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVBBboQwDDzHr7Co1AWJVu0VEJdy2Qf0tlKVhmgbLRgUzF4Q/Tq12UO3l0qRZuLM2BO7cXxynaXztj0Ect3ceqzCMHH0tq/ht3b1jodYA8jT7BjfKTAsYBTTQIyhzVEx5ugGmhgnbotC1IHO@EgZFmDMsVlCu@bCosz0S9w52d4vtIKRfma3uWFmrCpM3rSVDhxiceJEa/wVJsXDiQ4lmBXAfO8pMlzwr7vx/5pRvGMMV8tewmn4Y1PeyB5P@P0nNGYJawmgit4GSjNdwa657afSIDVax@HqlU@iNnfXZ9@PnXX@49O6S/qao5yEJWaSqTJ6niPhi4zZth8)</kbd>.